# Deploying Laravel 5 App to Server

Tags: laravel, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my Laravel 5 App to my server, but it's not working. It just appears a blank screen returning a 500 error. Here's what I did:

1. Changed the DB settings in the .env file to correspond to my server DB
2. Uploaded my local DB to the server DB
3. Uploaded the entire application folder to my subdirectory
4. Pointed the subdirectory to my public folder

Is there anything else I'm supposed to do?

P.S: I'm using cPanel on my server

EDIT: I've checked on my server the laravel error.log, and I got the following error: 
`I'm getting this error in the Laravel error log: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'PHP's json extension is required to use Monolog's NormalizerFormatter' in /home/petiscar/a3p/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/NormalizerFormatter.php:34`

a3p is the folder where I have everything except the public folder content
In a3p.painel.ventures(a3p being the subdomain here), I have the contents of the public folder

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, then there is probably a PHP error. Check your error logs to find out what's going wrong

Comment: All steps to deploy laravel 5 app is in [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/laravel/2410/deploy-laravel-5-app-on-shared-hosting-on-linux-server#t=201702151209428856144) Check there if you missed some step

Comment: What about checking the server logs file, you will find for sure more details.
Also you may enable debug in laravel configuration, it may provide more details..

500 error mostly occur because of file permissions or missing php extensions..

Comment: I've updated my question. @KuKeC, yes, I followed everything, and nothing changed

Comment: @AdamSilva Have you checked versions of php in local and deployed environment? Maybe version of PhP is problem

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to some permissions.
Try this:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R <project folder>
cd <project folder>
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Answer (score -1):

From the error it looks like you don't have php json extension installed, If you are using ubuntu server please try sudo apt-get install php-json and restart the apache.